# Linux udev rule does not appear to work

Tags: linux, fedora

I am writing an application that MUST run on Fedora Core 4. The application needs to access a USB device WITHOUT root privileges. Using libusb-1.0.8 I have successfully written the application except for one problem. If I do not have root privileges, libusb_open fails with -3 "Permission Denied".

I've read that I can alter the permissions of the device with a udev rule. And so I added 10-local.rules to /etc/udev/rules.d with the following line:

```
BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="040a", SYSFS{idProduct}=="4e00", MODE="0666"
```

I copied the above information from the output of udevinfo.

Even with the above rule, the device permissions always end up "0644" and I cannot open the USB device from a user application. Even after rebooting.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong?
Does Fedora Core 4 support what I am trying to do?
Thanks

Comment: The device that libusb is trying to access is /proc/bus/usb/??? where ??? changes with each insertion of the device. The udev log output says the kernel name is "hiddev0". If I put KERNEL=="hiddev*" in the rules file, I can successfully control the permissions on /dev/hiddev0 but I am still not able to open the device because I need the permissions on /proc/bus/usb/??? to be changed also.

Comment: Correction: the device is /proc/bus/004/??? where 004 appears to be the hub ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiying permissions for USB devices seems to be handled at least 3 different ways depending on the version of Linux (HAL, udev, hotplug, etc.). After several unsuccessful attempts I finally came across a site with accurate information.

For Linux 2.6.11 at least, the answer is hotplug. The solution is to create a custom usermap file in /etc/hotplug/usb. Use the built-in usermap (/etc/hotplug/usb.usermap) as an example. The usermap file specifies a script to execute when a matching device is connected. The script should also be located in /etc/hotplug/usb.

For example, I created /etc/hotplug/usb/myusbdvc.usermap with the VID and PID of my device and a script to execute named chmodmyusbdvc.

I also created /etc/hotplug/usb/chmodmyusbdvc with the follow contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${ACTION}" = "add" ] && [ -f "${DEVICE}" ]
then
  echo "changing ${DEVICE}" >> /tmp/debug-hotplug
  chmod 666 "${DEVICE}"
fi
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're keeping the "site with accurate information" a secret? :)

Answer (score 5):

Udev sets usb permissions *after* your script runs. Rename your rule so that the filename starts with a number greater than 50 (USB Permissions are set in the /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules). Since your script name is 10-..., it is run first, then the permissions are reset. Changing the filename to, for example, 99-local.rules. Then it will be one of the last scripts run, and none of the settings will be overwritten.

Source: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/02/fixing-android-phone-device-permissions-on-fedora-17/

Comment: You are just under 2 years late with your answer and I currently do not have a Fedora Core 4 setup to check to see if your solution will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5090", MODE="0666"
```

Conditions in the udev rules are tricky at best. You can check what parameter are available with the command:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=<device>
```

The output also includes the following notice:

```
A rule to match can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.
```

Also note the ending **S** in some attribute names. It appears in the parent devices, but not in the device itself.

Comment: Fedora Core 4 (linux 2.6.11) does not appear to have udevadm.

Comment: Fedora Core 4 (linux 2.6.11) does not appear to have udevadm. man udev lists available key words. I have tried SYSFS and ATTRS, BUS and SUBSYSTEM, with ACTION=="add" and without. I tried adding my device to the default rules file (50-udev.rules), no luck. Device still shows up with 0644.

Comment: Oh, I read Fedora Core 14, not 4! Have you tried enabling the udev debug log? Don't tell me that FC 4 doesn't have a log!

Comment: There is a configuration file and the log level was set to "err". I changed it to "info" but I am new to Linux and I have no idea where the log is.

Comment: I found that /var/log/messages has output from udev. I can see many messages indicating that ATTRS is an unknown key. I am going to clean things up and check the log.

Comment: Good work! and if that doesn't work, maybe you can try the "debug" log level. And you may want to look also to /var/log/syslog.